# i18next + React typescript : how to make api call with auth token in i18next?

Tags: react-typescript, react-i18next

When loading translations from an api, below code works fine but I have a requirement where this request in 'loadPath' should be sent with auth token otherwise will get an authentication error. Where do I send this token in 'backend' section of my i18next code?

```js
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';
import XHR from "i18next-http-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import i18n from 'i18next';

i18n.use(XHR).use(LanguageDetector)
.use(HttpApi)
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
    supportedLngs: ['en', 'es', 'pt', 'fr', 'gr', 'pl'],
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    detection: {
        order: ['htmlTag','querystring','path','cookie','localStorage','sessionStorage','subdomain'],
        caches: ['cookie', 'localStorage'],
        lookupQuerystring: 'lng',
        lookupCookie: 'i18next',
        lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
        lookupSessionStorage: 'i18nextLng'
    },
    backend: {
        loadPath: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE + 'locale/guest/en'}`,
        parse: function (data:any) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(res).data)
            return JSON.parse(res).data;
        },
    },
    interpolation: {escapeValue: false},
    debug: true,
    react: {useSuspense: false}
});

export default i18n;
```